# No xauth data warning X11 forwarding from macOS Catalina - linux

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding, xauth

I try to make a ssh connection from MacOS to linux. I've tried to follow several tips found on the internet, however I still get the following error when I tried to run xclock:

*X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0*

A little bit more information:

- It does not make any difference if I use ssh -X something@somewhere or ssh -Y something@somewhere
- I did install XQuartz and it is running on my Mac. xclock etc do work on Mac.
- When I add -vv when logging in I get the following: 
  "*debug1: No xauth program.
  Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
  debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.*"
- *which xauth* @ Mac gives the result /opt/X11/bin/xauth while *which xauth* logged in at the server gives /usr/bin/xauth --> Do note that at ssh_config and sshd_config (@Mac) the line XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth is present
- I uncommented *ForwardX11 yes* and *ForwardAgent yes* in ssh_config @Mac

If you will need any more information, please let me know! I really hope somebody could guide me to the right solution!

Comment: Try adding `XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth` to your `~/.ssh/config` under the stanza for the Linux host

Comment: With ~/.ssh/config do you mean the ssh_config file? Place that line just below 'Host*'?

Comment: No, I mean add the following like this to the top of your `~/.ssh/config` file... `Host *` then 2nd line... `XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth`

Comment: I am sorry, I am a little bit confused about which file is the ~/.ssh/config file. If I get into the folder ~/.ssh/ I see the files 'ssh_config' and 'sshd_config'.

Comment: The file `~/.ssh/config` is `~/.ssh/config` There certainly should not be a `sshd_config` in that directory because that's the config file for the system-wide daemon which certainly should not be in your HOME directory.

Comment: I added the file exactly how you suggested. However, the output of *which xauth* @ linux does not change. It still gives /usr/bin/xauth instead of /opt/X11/bin/xauth.

Comment: In addition to the above, I have `ForwardX11Trusted yes` in my `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: It will still give me the same error. Do I have to restart the ssh on the linux perhaps? I honestly cannot do that since I don't have the permission.

Comment: Turned out the memory I was allowed to use was full, that's what caused the problems! Thanks for your help @MarkSetchell

Comment: Cool - glad we got there in the end :-)